# Left JOIN syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am getting systax error on this query.

```
SELECT 
    e.post_id as id, e.start as start_date, 
    p.post_title, 
    c.name as category 
FROM 
    wp_ai1ec_events as e LEFT_JOIN wp_term_relationships as t ON e.post_id = t.object_id 
    LEFT_JOIN wp_term_relationships as t ON e.post_id = t.object_id 
    LEFT_JOIN wp_terms as c ON c.term_id = t.term_taxonomy_id
    LEFT_JOIN wp_posts as p ON p.ID = e.post_id
GROUP BY e.post_id
```

Actually I probably don't even need left join in this case since all should attach to one rows ...

```
Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT_JOIN wp_term_relationships as t ON e.post_id = t.object_id LEFT_JOIN w' at line 6
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no underscore in `LEFT JOIN`

`LEFT_JOIN` should be `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Thanks, stupid me, that's what happens when you code after 2 years.

Comment: It's always frustrating, yet somehow relieving, when the problem is a simple one.

Comment: I am only getting one result now, though I should have more results. Any idea ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. If you're certain there should be more then one row then you should consider asking a new question with the revised query and an explanation of why you're sure there should be more then one row. Sample data is always helpful.